# Prevent zoom in ios and android browser

Tags: html, css, mobile

Trying to find a way to prevent user to be able to zoom in a web page in latest ios and android.

I tried:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

...also:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

...and:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

But it is still zoomable

Any others solutions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually depends on the version of the browser you are using ,with each browser version having its own html code for restricting zooming.

**If you use android 2.2 or below** It is not supported at all
Android 2.3.x/3.x: By setting user-scalable=no you disable the scaling of the viewport meta tag yourself as well. This is probably why your width option is having no effect. To allow the browser to scale your content, you need to set user-scalable=yes, then to disable zoom you can set the min and max scale to the same value so it cannot shrink or grow. Toy with the initial scale until your site fits snugly.

Android 4.x: Same rule apply as 2.3.x except the min and max scales are not honored anymore and if you use user-scalable=yes the user can always zoom, setting it to 'no' means your own scale is ignored, this is the issue I'm facing now that drew me to this question... You cannot seem to disable zoom and scale at the same time in 4.x.

iOS/Safari (4.x/5.x tested): Scales work as expected, you can disable scaling with user-scalable=0 (keywords yes/no don't work in 4.x). iOS/Safari also has no concept of target-densitydpi so you should leave that out to avoid errors. You don't need min and max since you can switch off zooming in the expected manner. Only use width or you'll run into the iOS orientation bug

Chrome: Scales work as expected like they do in iOS, min and max are honored and you can switch off zooming by using user-scalable=no.

Conclusion: You can use some fairly simple JS to set the content accordingly after some basic browser/device detection. I know this type of detection is frowned upon but in this case it's almost unavoidable because each vendor has gone and done their own thing! Hope this helps people fighting the viewport, and if anyone has a solution for disabling zooming in Android 4.x WITHOUT the use of the viewport, please let me know.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,width=device-width,height=device-height,target-densitydpi=device-dpi,user-scalable=yes" />
```

Android 4.x Chrome browser (which I think is pre-installed in most countries): You can make sure the user cannot zoom and the page is fullscreen. The downside: you have to make sure the content has a fixed width. I haven't tested this on lower Android versions. To do this see the example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=620, user-scalable=no" />
```

iOS/Safari 8 Beta 4: There was a meta tag minimal-ui which worked fine in ios 7 versions ,however it has now been removed by Apple in this release.